# A specific case of quadratic forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, surfaces, quadratic-forms

I have a quadric as follows:

$$ax^2+by^2+bz^2+yz=0.$$
I am curious to know which shapes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ this equation describes for different value of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: This is a problem of classification of quadrics. You can look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric).

Answer (score 0):

if $b\ge \frac 12$, then there isn't enough room to move about.

$a^2 x^2, b^2 y^2, b^2 z^2,$ are all greater than $0.$

$b^2 y^2 + b^2 z^2 > yz.$

And the only solution is $(0,0,0).$

If $|b| < \frac 12 $, then you get a double cone.